# Finding historical data monthly data

Tags: data, finance, history

Where can I find historical data for WTI Price, gold price, CRB index for my research work?

Is there any website from where I can download these data?

Comment: Can you reformulate the question specifying the frequency, the specific data you need (by indicating you need for downloading the WTI time series price, you're not specific, since there are different time-series data named as that; see, for instance, Accumulation/distribution index WTI, Fast K WTI, ...), if you need for free data exclusively, etc. ?Moreover, look at the question database before ask the question for, since there are a lot of question about on-line database in which you can find free data. Alternatively, post the question on opendata.SE browsing on this site.

Comment: Agreeing with @Quantopic here, this seems to bring very little not already covered in the canonical free data question

Answer (score 1):

Although I think your question will be flagged for "basic knowledge" you can find free sources for this data including Yahoo Finance, Quandl.  Commercial data vendors also provide this information.

However, you really need to define what sort of data you are trying to find.  Spot prices (for physical delivery), spot prices (for cash settled) or futures data (for future physical delivery) or something else.

For example, "gold price" could be the cash-settled FX contract, LBMA "ring" settlements, Gold futures traded on CME/NYMEX, physical gold traded through venues like Perth Mint etc.

Full disclosure: Norgate/Premium Data offers commodities and futures data.